# How to install CR10 runtime on win7 64bit

Tags: vba, ms-access, crystal-reports, 64-bit, activex

I'm using the Crystal Report 10 viewer ActiveX control in an Access App I've written.  Works great in Office 2003 on 32bit versions of Windows.  The problem arrises when I try to run the program in 64 bit Windows (with 32bit Office).  I get the following error:

> Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object

I get this error on the following line of my VBA code.

```
Set rdApp = CreateObject("Crystalruntime.application.10")
```

How can I get this to work in 64bit?

Comment: 64bit Office, or 64bit Windows?

Comment: @TimWilliams -Good point, please see edit.

Comment: Maybe you need to install the 32-bit CR runtime (assuming the 64-bit one is currently installed)?  That's just a guess though - not a CR user....

Comment: @TimWilliams - Unfourtunately, both are already installed.

Comment: That is, both `CRRedist2008_x64.msi` and `CRRedist2008_x86.msi` are installed.

Comment: Tried uninstalling the 64-bit version? Again, just guessing...

Comment: While I am no expert on operating systems, I actually stumbled on this post in a roundabout way from here: [About VBA tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info). There was one particular part of the third paragraph that I thought may be useful. It states: " VBA 7 was released in 2010 to address the new 64-bit version of Microsoft Office..." If you developed your app in 2003 Office (VBA 6.5 or less) would it have compatibility issues with 64 bit versions??

Comment: @Marshall - Perhaps it would, but I'm not running 64 bit versions of office here, so I don't think this would apply.

Comment: How do you deploy your application? `CRRedist*.msi`-s you refer to are no fit as they are for *.NET applications*.

Comment: My application is a copy of the Access database.  On 32 bit windows all I do is copy the .mdb.  On 64 bit that doesn't work.

Comment: It can't be that way at all. The only way it's going to work is if CR 10 components are already installed on your 32-bit Win machines. PS. You can use `@so-user-name` for notifications in comments, you know.

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov - Ok, then I wonder if the components are installed as part of something else and I'm not aware of it.  How might I find out if that is happening?

Comment: If your `CreateObject(...)` works then CR 10 Viewer is installed and registered. You don't necessarily need to try it from VBA, one-liner .vbs with the same code is a fine test for that too. Finding out where the components came from will be tricky, to say the least. They certainly do not come with the OS or MS Office itself. You'll have to start with bare Win installation and add applications until one of them makes your test to work. But why not build your own distributive package? It is possible if you have CR 10 (you can't get redist from SAP as CR 10 is out of support for several years).

Comment: @MAW74656 Have you tried early binding? Are your components registered? There are **two** `regsvr32.exe` in 64bit Windows. `%systemroot%\System32\regsvr32.exe` and `%systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe`

Comment: You could create a new file called mytest.vbs and put "Set rdApp = CreateObject("Crystalruntime.application.10")" into it. Then run it by using %systemroot%\Syswow64\wscript.exe mytest.vbs to make sure that your CR 10 viewer is properly registered on the 32 bit copy of the Windows registry

Comment: @IlyaKurnosov -How can I build my own redist?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any specific experience with Crystal Report, but I do have some experience with installing components on a 64-bit Windows environment that were intended for 32-bit Windows, so here are some general suggestions of things to try:

- Before installing, try loosening the security privileges - I have Windows Server 2008; on this OS, they're under Start | Administrative Tools | Local Security Policy.  Many old installers are thwarted by these controls.  You'll want to return them to their defaults after the install.
- Make sure that you run the installer with admin privileges (right-click; run as Administrator).
- Examine the installation log for Crystal Report - it may indicate a failure registering a component.  In one instance, I was able to get the installation working by running the command to register the failed component manually, on an administrator-privileged command line (the command was in the log).
- If acceptable, try to create a [Windows Virtual Machine](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7) running a virtual Windows XP, and try the installations there (this might be a bit tedious, due to your need for MS Office).
- Take a look at [VMWare's ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/overview.html) - this is intended for packaging applications for administrators, but this was the solution we ended up using to shield one of our 32-bit apps from Windows 64-bit perils

Hope this helps; we struggled for awhile trying different things to get our legacy apps working on a 64-bit environment.